# VSTS Docker Integration fails to install

Tags: docker, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am trying to install the official Docker Integration to my VSTS. But it fails with the following message:

> Extension operation denied by event callback. All the task versions belonging to Contribution tasks/docker should have the same task id. Tasks with version 0.3.1 and version 0.3.4 do not have same ids.

I have no idea what this means. Anybody got an idea what this could be?

Comment: Do you do it VSTS build with Hosted Build agent? Which step/task you used? What're steps of your build definition? What's the detail build log?

Comment: Can't even get that far. If I go to the marketplace, search for **Docker Integration** and then choose my VSTS account and confirm the installation, it starts to install and then ends with that error.

Comment: The issue has been fixed now. You can install it and check the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been solved with a update that was rolled out.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce that issue too, I submit a feedback here: [Docker Integration install issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/3694), you can follow up it.

Update:

The issue has been fixed now.